# MacOS locked and cannot start applications

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My problem/question is quite hard to describe in words, so first here are two videos.

1. https://streamable.com/fmh0wr
2. https://streamable.com/hgr13g

As you can see in the videos, my mac is very messed up. Firstly, I am unable to open any application by pressing on the Dock icons. I then try to directly open them with the terminal, and indeed the GUI shows up, but I am unable to interact with it in anyway. In fact, the application doesn’t even show up in the “Force Quit Applications” tab, though it shows up in ps aux.

In the second video, I also tried opening system preferences, and since it’s a builtin application I assume it would work. However, it doesn’t, giving me the cryptic error “The application “%@“ can’t be opened.” while the GUI again shows up in the background but not interact-able.

If anyone could help me fix this I would be grateful. One more thing, I currently have a computational program running for a project that I cannot interrupt, so a logout or restart would not be possible...

If you require more info or me to try something, I will still be online in the next few hours, though only on phone (I do not have any browser window open and cannot open any new ones).

Thanks very much.

P. S. I am very lucky to have my VScode open  which has an internal terminal.

Comment: I've seen the M1s act like that when you're out of memory. Reboot is the fix - so I guess you'll have to wait & see if whatever you can't interrupt gives memory back when it's finished. I always keep Activity Monitor tucked away in Space 8, so I can see if that's my likely cause.

Comment: @Tetsujin hmm, but my program doesn’t take up any memory (from bin top)... or maybe i’m leaking memory somewhere... thanks! I will see what i can do. Also, this is not M1 mac, just intel

Comment: I've never seen an Intel run out of memory so I can't compare. The M1s [except the Studio] are all RAM starved anyway, so I see it on one of the new iMacs quite frequently. All the others have 32GB-64GB RAM, so it's rare they run out.

Comment: https://streamable.com/u9k9w7 @Tetsujin just an update, literally a minute ago my laptop display just stopped displaying anything and turned back as shown. However, the cursor is still there, the display is still “glowing”, and my connected usb keyboards are still on (ie the mac is still on). I think your theory of running out of memory is correct then :( Thanks for the help! Time to restart my program 